# SharePoint admin center Information

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-template

I am a bid confused about the data I have received after running the below Powershell script on SharePoint online:

`Get-SPOSite | select url, template, owner`

If you see the below image under the template, can you tell how I can recognize which one is SharePoint site collection, Teams and Planner? That would be great?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TEAMCHANNEL#0** : Teams Private Channel Site

**GROUP#0:** Office 365 Group associated Team Site

**EHS#1**: Team Site – SharePoint Online configuration(*A Team Site configured to allow organization members to edit, create new sites, and share with external users.*)

**SPSMSITE#0**: Personalization Site(*A site for delivering personalized views, data, and navigation from this site collection into My Site. It includes personalization specific Web Parts and navigation that is optimized for My Site sites.*)

**POINTPUBLISHINGHUB#0**:PointPublishing Hub(*A site template used to create a pointpublishing hub site.*)

**POINTPUBLISHINGTOPIC#0**: PointPublishing Topic(*A site template used to create a pointpublishing topic site.*)

**SRCHCEN#0** :Enterprise Search Center

**STS#0**: Team site (classic experience)

**PWA#0**:Project Web App Site

**STS#3**:Team site (no Office 365 group)

**APPCATALOG#0**: App Catalog Site

For more information, please refer to:

https://www.technologytobusiness.com/microsoft-sharepoint/sharepoint-online-site-template-id

https://vladtalkstech.com/2019/12/sharepoint-online-site-template-id-list-for-powershell.html